# How to parse this XML file

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I am new to programming in java and i have just learned how to parse an xml file. But i am not getting any idea on how to parse this xml file. Please help me with a code on how to get the tags day1 and their inner tags order1,order2

```
<RoutePlan>
<day1>
    <Order1>
    <customer> XYZ</customer>
    <address> INDIA </address>
    <data> 10-10-2011 </data>
    <time> 9.30 A.M </time>
    </Order1>

    <Order2>
    <customer> ABC </customer>
    <address> US </address>
    <data> 10-10-2011 </data>
    <time> 10.30 A.M </time>
    </Order2>
</day1>
```

I wrote the following code to retrieve. But i am only getting the data in order1 but not in order2

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document document = db.parse(file);
      document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
      System.out.println("Root Element: "+document.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
      NodeList node =  document.getElementsByTagName("day1");

      for(int i=0;i<node.getLength();i++){
          Node firstNode = node.item(i);
          Element element = (Element) firstNode;
          NodeList customer = element.getElementsByTagName("customer");
          Element customerElement = (Element) customer.item(0);
          NodeList firstName = customerElement.getChildNodes();
          System.out.println("Name: "+((firstName.item(0).getNodeValue())));

          NodeList address = element.getElementsByTagName("address");
          Element customerAddress = (Element) address.item(0);
          NodeList addName = customerAddress.getChildNodes();
          System.out.println("Address: "+((addName.item(0).getNodeValue())));

          NodeList date = element.getElementsByTagName("date");
          Element customerdate = (Element) date.item(0);
          NodeList dateN = customerdate.getChildNodes();
          System.out.println("Address: "+((dateN.item(0).getNodeValue())));


          NodeList time = element.getElementsByTagName("time");
          Element customertime = (Element) time.item(0);
          NodeList Ntime = customertime.getChildNodes();
          System.out.println("Time: "+((Ntime.item(0).getNodeValue())));
      }
```

Comment: *"Please help me with a code."*  Please ask a (specific) question.  Please show some effort.  Please explain where you are stuck.  SO is not a code generation machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I parse XML using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722140/how-can-i-parse-xml-using-java)

Comment: See my post; I started it out with a comment but was getting too long to fit in a comment hence the update post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can give you not one, not two, but three directions to parse this XML (there are more but let's say they are the most commons ones):

- DOM -> two good resources to start : [here](http://www.genedavis.com/library/xml/java_dom_xml_creation.jsp) and [here](http://www.roseindia.net/xml/dom/)
- SAX -> quickstart from official website: [here](http://www.saxproject.org/quickstart.html)
- StAX -> a good introduction: [here](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/07/20/introduction-to-stax.html)

Judging by the size of your XML document, I'd probably go for a DOM parsing, which gonna be the easiest to implement and to use (but if you have to deal with larger files, take a look at SAX for reading-only manipulations and StAX for reading and writing ones).

Comment: @user1019525 No problem, if you have any trouble implementing don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Roseindia is *not* a good resource IMO. They are content thieves and regularly present outdated/wrong content.

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma The examples and instructions given in this case are not THAT bad,on the contrary, so I don't think it's harmful to direct him there.

Comment: Beginners have no way of distinguishing between the good and the bad and as the ones helping out, it is always a good idea to warn them of the same, which I have done. YMMV.

Comment: @talnicolas Hi i am now able to get the values of only order1 but not for remaining. Is there anything wrong in my code

Comment: @user1019525 As Sanjay is explaining below, if you are the author of the XML file, I'd suggest you name your elements "day" and "order" and then add an attribute "id" (or even a child element) for example. Then you will be able to get every orders for every days and just iterate them with a simple loop.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting only "Order1" elements is because:

- You lock on the "day1" node.
- You retrieve the "customer" elements by tag name which returns 2 elements.
- You retrieve the first element and print its value and hence the second "customer" is ignored.

When working with DOM, be prepared to spin up multiple loops for retrieving data. Also, you are a bit misguided when it comes to representing your schema. You really don't need to name "elements" as "day1"/"order1" etc. In XML, that can be simply expressed by having multiple "day" or "order" elements which in turn automatically enforces ordering. An example XML would look like:

```
<route-plan>
    <day>
        <order>
            <something>
        </order>
    </day>
    <day>
        <order>
            <something>
        </order>
    </day>
</route-plan>
```

Now retrieving "day" elements is a simple matter of:

- Look up "day" elements by tag name
- For each "day" element

  - Look up "order" element by tag name
  - For each "order" element

    - Print out the value of "customer"/"address" etc.

Comment: Can you tell me some websites or books where i can find a detailed description for all the topics in java

Comment: Java is pretty huge, especially given its interaction with other technologies (XML, databases etc.). Is there anything specific you have in mind? Are you concerned about just "Java the core language" or are you looking at all the technologies surrounding it?

Comment: I want the technologies. Actually i don't even know what are the technologies that java is surrounded by and also i want to learn the basics perfectly

Comment: Start from [this page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) which provides a gist of all the technologies surrounding Java along with covering the [basics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html). After you are done with everything on that page, you should have a pretty good idea of how things are done in Java.