# Parsing XML file using Java

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I need to parse am XML file in Java and check some support based on the condition. I tried using the DOM for this.

```
  <Config>
      <Configuration>
        <Descriptor>
          <e id="0">
            <family>Rest</family>
            <supportedList>
              <_length>5</_length>
              <_type>TypeX[]</_type>
              <e id="0">value-1</e>
              <e id="1">value-2</e>
              <e id="2">value-3</e>
              <e id="3">value-4</e>
              <e id="4">value-5</e>
            </supportedList>
          </e>
          <e id="1">
            <family>Rest1</family>
            <supportedList>
              <_length>5</_length>
              <_type>TypeX[]</_type>
              <e id="0">value1-1</e>
              <e id="1">value1-2</e>
              <e id="2">value1-3</e>
              <e id="3">value1-4</e>
              <e id="4">value1-5</e>
            </supportedList>
          </e>
          </Descriptor>
      </Configuration>
    </Config>
```

In the above XML file,I need to go through the "e" block and then Descriptor block, and then search for Family - Rest1 and then iterate through supportedList. Check if supportedList contains user provided value if it exists then return true.

I tried using a DOM parser but I am not able to parse the file properly. The actual XML file that I am working on, is of 20K lines and has too much data. Any easy solution on this.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: XPath would be better than DOM for this

Comment: the actual file has quite a sensitive data and the same thing I have used it in my code as well so could not share the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I parse XML using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722140/how-can-i-parse-xml-using-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
    xPathExpression = xpath.compile("//family[text()='Rest1']/e");

    NodeList list = (NodeList) xPathExpression
        .evaluate(xml, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

And on XPath syntax, it suffices to search for "XPath cheat sheet" or so.